# Java custom pixel rendering engine bug

Tags: java, rendering, game-engine, pixel

I'm developing my own game engine called FGame, and I am having this graphical error that is really bugging me, and i'm not sure where the problem lies. For graphics, I am using a custom Image class which has a 2d array of pixels to store its data. I also have a screen class, which extends the Image class, and the screen's pixel data is used to draw to the JFrame through the BufferedImage java class.

If I am drawing an image, and I move it around the screen, there is a graphical bug that distorts the pixels in a vertical line at certain spots on the screen.

Here is a video showing the bug I am trying to describe: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnGCuHW5neI, and here is a link to the source code: https://github.com/Frechetta/FGame.

Comment: +1 for good sources for investigation

Comment: What do you mean distorts?

Comment: As an image moves horizontally, pixels of that image that cross certain points on the x-axis are moved up or down by one pixel, and then back again once they are on the other side of that point.

Comment: Seems like screen tearing, does this happen if you set the layoutmanager to null and not to borderlayout? You don't want the layoutmanager to try repainting when you are doing active rendering.

Comment: Well setting the layout to null doesn't let me draw anything to the screen. It reduces the JFrame to just the border of the window and takes the contents away. And commenting out that line doesn't change anything.

Comment: Yeah, @arynaq is right. I've just tried your code without layout manager and it works with no tearing. Change your layout setting code to `frame.setLayout(null);  
        frame.setSize(getPreferredSize());
        this.setSize(getPreferredSize());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @arynaq and @Max for helping me with my problem. I'll post my old code and new code for anybody else who runs into this problem.

Old Code:

```
frame = new JFrame(nameA);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.pack();
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

New code:

```
frame = new JFrame(nameA);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLayout(null);
this.setSize(getPreferredSize());
frame.add(this);
frame.pack();
frame.setSize(getPreferredSize());
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```